# How to control a Simulink simulation from Python?

Tags: python, matlab, simulink

I want to control a Simulink simulation from Python, so I used the MATLAB Engine API as refered to in the [official documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html).

First, I want to open Simulink and run the Simulink model which I already have. I tried writing a Python script to open Simulink , but nothing is working. I tried the following code to open Simulink

```py
import matlab.engine
eng=matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.sim("mysimulinkmodelname")
```

How can I open the Simulink model from within Python and where do I save it?